# FirebaseUI not calling my delegate function in SwiftUI

Tags: firebase, swiftui

My email signing was successful, but for some reason my specified delegate function is not getting called. I tried setting a break point, but it seems like the delegate function was not invoked at all.. Can someone help me?

```
struct FirebaseUIView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UINavigationController {
        let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()!
        
        // supported login methods
        let providers: [FUIAuthProvider] = [FUIEmailAuth()]
        authUI.providers = providers
        authUI.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        // Show FirebaseUI
        let authViewController = authUI.authViewController()
        return authViewController
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UINavigationController, context: Context) { }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, FUIAuthDelegate {
        let parent: FirebaseUIView
        
        init(_ parent: FirebaseUIView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith authDataResult: AuthDataResult?, error: Error?) {
            print("\n\n\n\nhello: \(authDataResult?.user)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just my thoughts, do u really need to return UINavigationController instead of UIViewController by default there?

Comment: tbh, I was just following one of the examples I was following. Does it make differences?